# How do I send more output after a user prompt with bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I'm working on a bash script, and would like to put a disclaimer on the bottom of the main menu of the script.

I need to echo several menu options for the user to select.
Do a read for the user input.

My problem is that read stops, and waits for user input..
Is it possible to prompt the user, while also displaying a disclaimer at the bottom of the screen (below the user prompt)?

Comment: It's possible, using something like `ncurses` or ASNI escape characters, but is it worth the effort? Just display the disclaimer following the menu, but before the prompt. Or acknowledge that the users are unlikely to read or pay attention to it and just skip it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I completely understand your question, but you can write a disclaimer at the bottom of the screen like this and then return to the top to ask for input...

```
#!/bin/bash
lines=$(tput lines)            # Get number of lines in Terminal
while :; do
   tput clear                  # Clear screen
   echo                        # Leave space for prompt
   echo
   echo Option 1:
   echo Option 2:
   echo Option 3:
   echo
   tput cup $lines 0           # Put cursor to foot of screen
   tput smso                   # Enable BOLD (Stand Out Mode)
   echo -n Disclaimer - this may be rubbish.
   tput rmso                   # Disable BOLD (Remove Stand Out Mode)
   tput cup 0 0                # Put cursor to top of screen
   echo -n Enter your choice: 
   read x
done
```

Press `Ctrl-C` to exit, by the way.

**Note:**

The following may be useful to you:

`tput sc` - Save Cursor Position

`tput rc` - Restore Cursor Position

You can also embed `tput` commands inside `echo` statements, if you use `echo -e` like this:

```
echo -e "Plain $(tput smso)Bold$(tput rmso) Plain"
```

Plain `Bold` Plain

Comment: Thanks! Using tput sc, and tput rc - I was able to get everything on screen, and jump the cursor back up to the "promp" line.. after doing calling `read opt` for my case.

Comment: Excellent! Pleasure to be of assistance.

Answer (score 0):

If your user is supposed to chose from several menu options, you may want to use `select` instead of `read`.

Processing of the answer is easier and faster and it reduces the risk of the user mistyping.

*(I would have put this as a comment, would I have been able to)*